# Access I18nService without define in argument or construct in class in nest js

Tags: nestjs

I am using nest js
i want to make I18nService helper function

problem is when i use directly I18nService in helper class then it show error
[Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 't')]

mean i dont want to define like in every class when access I18nservice

```
constructor(private readonly i18nService: I18nService) {}
```

or

```
async getHello(@I18n() i18n: I18nContext)
```

i have this helper file but this trans function not work

```
import { HttpStatus, Inject, Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { I18n, I18nContext, I18nService } from 'nestjs-i18n';

@Injectable()
export class Helper {
    @Inject('i18n')
    private i18n: I18nService;

    static SuccessResponse(data: any[], messageKey?: string, replacement?: any[]) {
        return { success: true, status: HttpStatus.OK, message: 'Success', data };
    }

    static ErrorResponse(data: any[] | null = null, statusCode: number = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, messageKey?: string, replacement?: any[]) {
        return { success: false, status: statusCode, message: '', data };
    }

    static Trans(key: string, translationArgs: any[] = [], lang: string = 'en') {
        const instance = new Helper();
        return instance.i18n.t(key, { lang: lang, args: translationArgs });
    }
}
```

when i call this trans function

```
return Helper.Trans('message.HELLO', [], 'es');
```

it give error

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 't')

i want to inject service one time in class dont inject again and again function argument